# Defining a variable inside isset function

Tags: php, isset

I'm trying to save lines by trying to define a variable in `isset()`.
Currently the only way I could make this work is this:

```
$setpass_accinfo = $dbconn->query("SELECT id,name,password FROM users WHERE id=" . $dbconn->real_escape_string(_GET('id')));
$setpass_accinfo_row = isset($setpass_accinfo->num_rows) ? $setpass_accinfo->fetch_assoc() : false;
```

So, I'm trying to combine those two lines into one, if you know what I mean. Something like this for example:

```
$setpass_accinfo = isset(($setpass_accinfo = $dbconn->query("SELECT id,name,password FROM users WHERE id=" . $dbconn->real_escape_string(_GET('id'))))->num_rows) ? $setpass_accinfo->fetch_assoc() : false;
```

The issue is that it gives me an error about using `$setpass_accinfo` and I don't know how to fix it or if it's even possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: echo/var_dump `$setpass_accinfo` and what do you get? same for `$setpass_accinfo_row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$setpass_accinfo_row = $dbconn->query("SELECT ...")->fetch_assoc() ?: false;
```

- `$dbconn->query()` returns mysqli result
- `$dbconn->query()->fetch_assoc()` returns:

  - An associative array that corresponds to the fetched row
  - `NULL` if no row was found
- The `?:` is the shorter form of ternary operator which, in this case, returns the array or `false`

Note that it does not check if the query executed successfully.

Comment: If for instance the `id` is `ab` and should only be a number, it will show up an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in..`. Could it be handled too?

Comment: Then you can use the other answer, but you can skip the `!empty` check. Ternary operator checks for turthiness of expression and false is... false.

Comment: `$setpass_accinfo_row = ($setpass_accinfo = $dbconn->query("SELECT ...")) ? $setpass_accinfo->fetch_assoc() : false;`

Answer (score 2):

This can get a little messy at times but:

```
$setpass_accinfo_row = !empty($setpass_accinfo = $dbconn->query("SELECT id,name,password FROM users WHERE id=" . $dbconn->real_escape_string(_GET('id')))) ? $setpass_accinfo->fetch_assoc() : false;
```

Connot use isset() on the result of an expression
When you use single equal in an if statement, the $variable is assigned the value of the right side of the equal, then the variable is evaluated in the `empty()`, in this case. And precedence dictates the it is defined before the ternary operation is reached.

Comment: It's not working either, it says there is an unexpected '='.

Comment: There's no missing bracket.

Comment: Had to make a fix. Should be good now. You can't do the evaluation like that in isset, so the only way to do it is with empty.

Comment: plus `$_GET('id')` should have square brackets, not round This isn't a function

Comment: Yeah I saw that and fixed it. I copied OP's which was missing it.

Comment: `_GET` is a function I made for personal and more convenient use ;)

Comment: still missing a bracket for it. Put that in an IDE/code editor, you'll see

Comment: Oh hahaha. I'll change it back. That is a really really bad practice.

Comment: @OmerAviv how can `$setpass_accinfo_row = !empty($setpass_accinfo = $dbconn->query("SELECT id,name,password FROM users WHERE id=" . $dbconn->real_escape_string(_GET('id'))) ? $setpass_accinfo->fetch_assoc() : false;` possibly work? I don't believe you. There's a missing bracket. Edit: ok, now it's been added.

Comment: Whatever missing brackets, I add them after copying the code.

Comment: @OmerAviv Sure, you know... Robert knows, and I know. But future visitors to the question/answer may not know. Therefore, having proper syntax in an answer is very important.

Comment: The code doesn't show any error, but it won't work since the page isn't loading.. :(